# AlertDialog changing look of font (size, colour, align)

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to change properties of my AlertDialog inside of my game, currently I'm building it with this way:

> private static final int DIALOG_INFO = 1;
>
> ```
> private Dialog dialog;  
>
> @Override  
> protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)  
> {  
>     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
>
>     switch (id)   
>     {       
>         case DIALOG_INFO:  
>
>             builder.setTitle("Game Information - Diego 1.0.1");  
>             builder.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);  
>             builder.setMessage("Test there \n\n");  
>             builder.setCancelable(true);  
>
>             dialog = builder.create();  
>             dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);                
>             break;  
>     }   
>     return dialog;  
> }
> ```

And if player clicked certain button, I'm showing this dialog with this way:

```
showDialog(DIALOG_INFO);
```

Everything works, but I decided to change look of font used in this dialog, with this way:

> TextView textView = ((TextView)
>   dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message));
>           textView.setTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
>           textView.setTextSize(13);
>           textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

But code works only, if I put this code after showDialog(DIALOG_INFO); which means I have to create new object (TextView textView = ...) everytime I'm showing dialog, and my question is, can't I do it only once while creating dialog?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your own contentView for AlertDialog:

```
.....
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_DIALOG_LAYOUT, null);
builder.setView(rootView);
.....
```

And markup your dialog layout in xml.